# Running into errors while publishing ASP.NET Core Web API with migration

Tags: asp.net-core, deployment, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, publish

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caoZi.png)

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET Core Web API with migrations to Azure, but have been running into the following errors under: Settings > Entity Framework Migrations:

```
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef
```

> The tool package could not be restored.
> Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:
>
> - You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
> - A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
> - The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
> - You mistyped the name of the tool.

I realized that the above command installs whatever the latest version of `dotnet-ef` is, which at the moment is version 8.0.0. The problem is, this version is incompatible with .NET 6.0 (my framework version).

My question: how do I update the command to install a specific version of `dotnet-ef` compatible with .NET 6.0?

I've looked up: How to update default commands for `dbContext`, Entity Framework. Couldn't find anything substantial.

Comment: try downgrading the version to 6

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for nuget package try below command

dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 6.0.0